# Ruby and Tmail; Hostname of relaying server?

Tags: ruby, tmail

I am using Ruby and Tmail to retrieve a series of emails from the server.

Is there any way to determine the hostname of the server that relayed the email message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's [TMail::ReceivedHeader#by](http://tmail.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/TMail/ReceivedHeader.html#M000298).

```
mail = TMail::Mail.parse(File.read("mail"))
mail["received"].each do |received|
  puts "Received by: #{received.by}"
end
```